# Javascript Link to tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, hashtag

I have a full tab system working with the following code. When you click on A LI link it hides the other divs and shows the selected div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();

    function init() {

      // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
      var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
      for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
        if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
          var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
          var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
          tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
          contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
        }
      }

      // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
      // highlight the first tab
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
        if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
        i++;
      }

      // Hide all content divs except the first
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        i++;
      }
    }

    function showTab() {
      var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

      // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
      // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( id == selectedId ) {
          tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
        } else {
          tabLinks[id].className = '';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        }
      }

      // Stop the browser following the link
      return false;
    }

    function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
      }
    }

    function getHash( url ) {
      var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
      return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
    }

    //]]>
    </script>
```

I want to be able open the tabs via this links. So that when i visit `index.php#hello` it will link to the div with the id `hello`. I tried simply visiting the link but this did not work... Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Instead of using your `getHash()` function, why not use `window.location.hash`? Also, you should call `showTab()` on page load. You don't seem to be executing it after the page loads, and only when you click a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you run `init()` on page load, just add the following inside that function:

```
if( window.location.hash )
    showTab();
```

You have the function `showTab()` executing when you click links to set the proper tab open, but not when the page loads, so it doesn't know to execute your code. Having it run once if a hash location exists will help get you what you need.

Comment: Where abouts in the init. I have it exciting from a onLoad in the body.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it just needs to run.